# How do you read or write to GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi 4 without using a high-level library?

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, embedded, raspberry-pi4

I'm attempting this Rust, but the code is segfaulting:

```rust
unsafe {
    const PERIPH_BASE: u32 = 0xFE000000;
    const GPIO_BASE: u32 = PERIPH_BASE + 0x00200000;

    // Turn on pin GPIO 24
    ptr::write_volatile(GPIO_BASE as *mut u32, 1 << 24);
}
```

I'm suspicious this is due to using the wrong address. The only info on the subject I've found is a RP forum post. I'm unable to find info in the RP4 datasheet, and can't find a manual for the Broadcom chipset.

I'm running this code on Raspian on a Raspberry Pi SBC. I'm attempting to generalize the code to make it easier to port to true embedded later, hence why I am avoiding libraries.

I've looked through rppal and embedded-hal, but was surprised to not find the solution. I've looked through every file in [the `gpio` module](https://github.com/golemparts/rppal/tree/97554ba2bafe55f0b1a3671e57db1a1daf58c095/src/gpio)'s code. mem.rs and ioctl.rs look the closest, but I've been unable to find it.

Comment: If you're using Raspbian, then applications cannot access the registers directly (in any language), which explains why your code segfaults. They need to go through some kernel driver (which libraries can abstract so that your code runs either on bare metal or with an OS).

Comment: You nailed the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing directly into the process address space. I think you might have more success writing directly to physical memory. Here is [how RPPAL does it](https://github.com/golemparts/rppal/blob/97554ba2bafe55f0b1a3671e57db1a1daf58c095/src/gpio/mem.rs#L127-L143):

```rust
let mem_file = OpenOptions::new()
    .read(true)
    .write(true)
    .custom_flags(O_SYNC)
    .open(PATH_DEV_MEM)?;

// Memory-map /dev/mem at the appropriate offset for our SoC
let mem_ptr = unsafe {
    libc::mmap(
        ptr::null_mut(),
        GPIO_MEM_SIZE,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_SHARED,
        mem_file.as_raw_fd(),
        (device_info.peripheral_base() + device_info.gpio_offset()) as off_t,
    )
};
```

You can access physical memory at `/dev/mem` in Raspbian but you might need root.

Comment: This answers my question entirely. With pulling more code from rrpal as specified here, and the `libc` lib, it works.

Comment: Glad I could help!